# capybara with selenium wait for onchange event

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, capybara

I have a form field with an onchange event which inserts some text into the page.

```
fill_in "password", :with => 'test' # should trigger onchange which inserts the text below into the page
page.should have_content('very insecure')
```

Now when I test this with cucumber/ capybara/ selenium with firefox it works without any problems. Using selenium with chrome, capybara complains the text is not found in the document.

Now I wonder how to fix this. Do I need to manually invoke the event (which would be real hacky imo)? Or do I simply have to wait for all events being processed (how?) between my fill_in and should have_content methods?

Comment: The has_content method should already be waiting for the text to appear, so I don't think that's the problem. Seems more likely to be a webdriver/chrome issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you feel that it is an issue that you need to wait longer, I would throw in a "sleep 3" before the page.should.  There are also raw Selenium commands for this but it is best to avoid them.